# Reading the String and Int from file, and then looped through?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get it so when it reads through the file, it splits every thing before a comma into an element, and then since there are 10 integer grades, those need to be parsed into an int and then calculated for an average. However, I'm unsure of how to actually accomplish this. I've been looking for a solution for hours and I just can't seem to figure it out. I would really appreciate some help here, as I'm currently running out of brain cells. 
Thank you, - from someone new to programming.

The assignment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7E9x.png

The .txt file I'm reading from: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxCi4.png

My current code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
        System.out.println("Enter raw grades filename:");
        userInput = scanner.nextLine();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(userInput));

        String line = "";
        String txtSplitBy = ", ";

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] splitLine = line.split(", ");
        String name = splitLine[0];
        String scores = splitLine[2];

        int i = Integer.parseInt(scores);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The split has only ',' and not ', ' in the text file ?

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(userInput));

String line;
String txtSplitBy = ",";

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    int score = 0;
    String grade;
    String[] splitLine = line.split(txtSplitBy);
    String name = splitLine[0];
    for ( int i =1; i <= 10; i++) {
        score += Integer.parseInt(splitLine[i]);
    }
    if ( score < 50 ) {
        grade = "B";
    }else if ( score < 60 ) {
        grade = "A";
    }else {
        grade = "S";
    }
    System.out.println(name +"," + (score/10) + "," + grade );
}
```

You need to add your grade logic here.

Comment: Do only what he asks you to do, it's his/her homework!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version, I kept it simple, after all, it's your homework!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;
    System.out.println("Enter raw grades filename:");
    userInput = scanner.nextLine();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(userInput));

    String line = "";
    String txtSplitBy = ","; // Changed from ', ' to ','

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] splitLine = line.split(",", 2); // The threee caps the number of splits
        String name = splitLine[0];

        ArrayList<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] rawGrades = splitLine[1].split(","); // List of grades as string

        for(String rawGrade : rawGrades) {
            grades.add(Integer.parseInt(rawGrade));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can have both `ArrayList<Integer> grades` and `String[] grades`.

Comment: I have fixed it now